# Convert ARM assembly to gnu assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

I've got a set of .s files from ARM that run on the ARM tool chain, but we're using the gnu tool chain.

Is there a conversion script/tool/method that will convert the assembly from the one format to the other?  Doing it by hand seems...dangerous.

Comment: If your toolchains support a common object format, you can assemble your files with one and disassemble with the other.  That'll get you most of the way there.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have the arm toolchain in-house.  Too expensive, which is why everyone uses gnu.  If we had that, then you're right, doing the conversion and disassembling both and comparing would be the way to go.

Comment: I once worked in a place that had full access to the ARM toolchain but needed to deliver binary libs to clients who used GNU / GCC. Our solution involved disassembly of the arm-built libs and passing the result through a very large amount of Perl to convert to GAS compatible assembly, and pushing the result into the GNU toolchain to build the final lib. The project that did the conversion was shared by teams and was a substantial effort to produce from my vague memory of what I was told.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced a script/tool would be less dangerous than doing it by hand.

How much effort converting the code is depends to large extent on how many non-basic features (macros, named registers ...) are in use in the code.

The syntax of the instructions generally does not differ (although there may be certain immediate modifiers permitted in one format but not the other).
The comment syntax differs, but ';' -> '@' should be a reasonably safe search-and-replace.

Where most code differs is in labels (as requires ':' after label name, armasm doesn't), but more importantly the assembler directives.

Comment: Yes, there are lots of macros and who knows what other advanced features I'll find when I start digging into it more.  I'm a ASIC verification guy, and these are a set of canned tests from ARM to make sure the our ARM integration was done correctly before we tapeout the ASIC.  So there's also the issue of getting this exactly correct, or it could be very expensive.

I was hoping this was a common problem that had already been solved.  If there's not a way to do the conversion in a way we can be confident, my next step is to talk to management about getting a license for ARM's toolchain.

Comment: You're making an ASIC and a compiler license is too expensive?  Sounds like a weird situation.

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it.  Part of it is the SW team uses the gnu tools already (and they're happy with it), so that's what we use, and part of it is needing to justify it to the bean counters.  If there's not a graceful way to do the conversion for these signoff tests, I'd call that pretty good justification for at least one licence.

Comment: Then I'd suggest the license cost will be lower than the engineering cost of the conversion. Especially considering that the validation of an ASIC hangs in the balance if anything goes wrong.